# Неправильно работает поиск корреляции

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, статистика

Есть такой код. Он ищет корреляции среди разных акций Yahoo finance. Единственное что он не умеет - строить корреляции для множества инструментов (6 штук построит, а 10 уже не сможет). Вопрос - как научить? Например я хочу использовать тикеты акций не в формате ('SAN.MC', 'GAM.MC', 'BBVA.MC' ... , а чтобы они были записаны файлом.

```js
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()

start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 31)

symbols = ('SAN.MC', 'GAM.MC', 'BBVA.MC', 'GAS.MC', 'ENG.MC', 'REP.MC')

prices_df = pd.DataFrame()
for symbol in symbols:
    df = data.DataReader(symbol, 'yahoo', start, end)
    prices_df.loc[:, symbol] = df['Adj Close']

prices_df.tail()

numlines=len(prices_df.columns)
mypalette=Spectral6[0:numlines]

# график
p = figure(width=1000, height=600, x_axis_type="datetime") 
color_ix = 0
for symbol in symbols:
    p.line(prices_df.index.values, prices_df[symbol].values, legend=symbol, line_color=mypalette[color_ix], line_width=2)
    color_ix += 1
show(p)
# 

corr_df = prices_df.corr(method='pearson')
corr_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ответ на ваш главный вопрос:

> не получается много инструментов считать

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

# читаем файл со списком инструментов в список   
symbols_fn = r'C:\Temp\.data\631336\symbols.txt'
with open(symbols_fn) as f:
    stocklist = f.read().splitlines()

start = '2016-01-01'
end = '2016-12-31'

# читаем все "инструменты" одной коммандой в Pandas.Panel
x = wb.DataReader(stocklist, 'yahoo', start, end)

# 2D срез (DataFrame) по 'Adj Close', параллельно освобождаем память:
x = x.loc['Adj Close']
print(x)
```

Результат:

```
In [5]: x
Out[5]:
                  AAPL        ADI        ADM        AIV       AMAT        ANTM         AON        APA        APC        APH       ARNC
Date
2016-01-04  102.612183  52.665440  34.491400  38.079797  18.117888  136.506876   89.304015  43.361861  48.950834  50.392948  21.447743
2016-01-05  100.040792  52.278481  34.876350  39.049798  18.137507  138.497457   89.845493  42.483497  48.343058  49.828294  20.475857
2016-01-06   98.083025  50.053454  34.029462  38.608015  17.391996  135.114436   88.486878  37.603701  43.610380  48.649455  19.018028
2016-01-07   93.943473  48.776478  33.221070  38.387124  16.881909  132.800261   87.197185  35.671303  39.963728  46.896053  18.267028
2016-01-08   94.440222  48.350822  33.095960  37.657219  16.469917  129.564352   85.671207  35.768901  40.412088  46.192713  17.825261
2016-01-11   95.969420  49.502031  32.874615  37.897319  16.362014  125.867552   85.070668  34.217126  37.612334  45.836088  17.670643
...
```

PS хранить данные рекомендую в HDF5 - очень быстро, хранит инфу о типах данных (`dtypes`), позволяет читать данные выборочно (т.е. фильтровать при чтении с диска - незаменимо при работе с наборами данных, которые не помещаются целиком в памяти), поддерживает сжатие, широко распространенный формат и т.д.

Пример:

```
# запись
x.to_hdf(r'C:\Temp\.data\631336\data_panel.h5',
         'my_id', format='t',
         complib='blosc', complevel=5,
         data_columns=True)
# чтение
df = pd.read_hdf(r'C:\Temp\.data\631336\data_panel.h5', 'my_id')
```

Результат:

```
In [10]: df.shape
Out[10]: (252, 11)

In [11]: df.dtypes
Out[11]:
AAPL    float64
ADI     float64
ADM     float64
AIV     float64
AMAT    float64
ANTM    float64
AON     float64
APA     float64
APC     float64
APH     float64
ARNC    float64
dtype: object
```